# Error on find_package when overriding add_library() in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm overriding `add_library()` in order to do some post-processing on each library. This works well for the libraries defined in my codebase, however it also applies on external dependencies added via find_package (e.g. Qt) and throws an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/Qt/lib/cmake/Qt5DBus/Qt5DBusConfigExtras.cmake:19 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  Qt5::qdbusxml2cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/Qt/lib/cmake/Qt5DBus/Qt5DBusConfig.cmake:144 (include)
  /esm/Qt/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

I've defined the override as follows:

```
function(add_library target)
_add_library(${target} ${argn})
message("################# PROCESSING LISTDIR" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ":" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE}) #${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
endfunction()
```

Everything works properly without the override.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: [Do Not Redefine CMake Commands](https://crascit.com/2018/09/14/do-not-redefine-cmake-commands/) ;-) (I was not aware that this is possible at all. Out of curiosity, I googled a bit and found this link.)

Comment: `${argn}` it's `ARGN`

Comment: Thanks @Scheff'sCat for sharing. The background of the question is that I'm attempting to write an extension to cmake that would improve the graphviz dependency graph generation functionality. The override option seemed to allow me to do just that. Too bad it wasn't meant to be.

Comment: @KamilCuk cmake is essentially completely case-insensitive. It can't tell the difference between ARGN and argn.